# How to update a table rows with the pattern from first 10 records (similar to what fill handle in excel)

Tags: sql-server

I want to update the below table where name is null to  repeat the pattern from first 10 rows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m54X7.png)

sql:

declare @name varchar(255)
set @name = select distinct name from #temp
update #temp
set name = @name
where name is not null

---

Obviously the above the query will not work due to multiple values. I want to update the table where it's null to fill with the pattern from above.

Comment: Despite some superficial resemblance, SQL tables and spreadsheet sheets are quite different beasts. Trying to apply spreadsheet thinking to SQL tables (or vice versa) will often lead to trying to do things "the wrong way".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with Damien's suggestion that you not conflate databases and spreadsheets, you can do this quite easily with window functions and the modulo operator:

```
WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT dt, 
         name, 
         seq  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt), 
         c    = COUNT(*) OVER()
  FROM #temp
  WHERE name IS NOT NULL
),
y AS 
(
  SELECT dt, 
         name, 
         seq  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt)
  FROM #temp WHERE dt > (SELECT MAX(dt) FROM x)
) 
UPDATE y SET y.name = x.name
FROM x INNER JOIN y
ON x.seq % x.c = y.seq % x.c;
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wbOFWvC_).

This doesn't validate, though, that the non-null values are all contiguous at the beginning - if you need the query to validate that, it's considerably more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I am just posting an Answer according to your picture.

I think if you want to use it some where else , then you should change it. (It is not General)

```
update
   t1 
set
   t1.name = t2.name 
from
   (
      select  *,row_number() over (order by dt) - 1 as rn 
      from
         (
            select
               * 
            from
               tbl1 
            where
               name is not null
         )
         as a 
   )
   as t1 
   inner join
      (
         select
            name,
            day,
            mod(rn, 10) as rn 
         from
            (
               select *,row_number() over (order by dt) - 1 as rn 
               from
                  (
                     select
                        * 
                     from
                        tbl1 
                     where
                        name is null
                  )
                  as b
            )
            as tmp 
      )
      as t2 
      on t1.day = t2.day 
      and t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Comment: What is `mod()`? Is this for something other than Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: The MOD() function in MySQL is used to find the remainder of one number divided by another. In MSSQL you can use % operator instead

Comment: I know what MOD() does, but the question is about Microsoft SQL Server, and MOD() does not exist in Microsoft SQL Server, so while an answer using MOD() might be great for MySQL users, very few of them are even going to see this question.